# Converting Binary Audio Text to Audio File

Tags: node.js, audio, amazon-s3

I'm using node and downloading media for bandwidth.com which returns binary data of the audio (wav) file but I am having difficulty converting it to an audio file and uploading it to s3. The audio doesn't play after uploading it to s3.

```
  const file = {
    Body: media.content,
    ContentType: media.contentType,
    Key: `voicemails/${fileName}`,
    ContentEncoding: 'base64'
  };

  bucket.putObject(file, (err, data) => {});
```

Comment: `ContentEncoding: 'base64'` is possible but seems somewhat unlikely.  If you have a reason to believe this to be true, you don't appear to have mentioned it.  Save the file using `application/octet-stream`, then download and open with a hex editor and you should be able to easily tell if it's really in base64.

Comment: Ah yes, you can ignore base64, I was trying that method.

Comment: can you play the wav file from bandwidth.com  ?  is it compressed ?  wav is typically not compressed yet audio over the wire more often than not is compressed

Comment: @ScottStensland Yes, the file works from bandwidth.com

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you may be leaving out some relevant details/code.  From what you wrote, best guess is to follow instructions like these for binary files https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/binary-support-for-api-integrations-with-amazon-api-gateway/ and avoid base64 encoding and base64 content type.

Comment: Ah yes, you can ignore base64, I was trying that method.